# How to use Accessibility Shortcuts for enabling Display Color Filters?

Tags: macos, display, shortcut, menu-bar, accessibility

As part of my evening routine, I have enabled Dark Mode and Night Shift to turn on in the evening. In addition, I like to turn on the grayscale/greyscale color filter option in `System Preferences > Accessibility > Display > Color Filters > Enable Color Filters` as shown in the screenshot below (1).

[image]

Now, instead of drilling down into the appropriate submenu to turn the color filter `on | off`, is there a way to add this option to the Accessibility Shortcuts list from the drop-down menu bar button as shown in the screenshot (2)?

--

Just to be thorough in my question, I want to show that the existing shortcuts do not include `Color Filters` as shown below. I do not see an option to add additional/new shortcuts.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On macOS Big Sur., you can enable that option here…

[image]

Comment: I dont know who downvoted you but this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: This was suggested as an edit to my answer.  I don't believe my post should have been edited. However, it is worthy to post as a comment... If you leave Color Filters only option enabled then command+alt+F5 or 3xtouchId will toggle option automatically without need of secondary click on Accessibility menu

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to use an AppleScript saved as an application. Double-clicking it (saved on the desktop, for example) allows for making the changes quite easily.

See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/413540/248480.

Still, this doesn't answer the original question so I would look forward to other responses.