Make it easier to toggle color filters
I need a more convenient way to toggle this option.
I'm happy for it to be a toggled at a keystroke, an option in my top menu bar, or an option in this thing:

I initially tried ChatGPT to write an applescript, but it didn't work.
Any suggestions?


this question may partially answer your question https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/416475/how-to-use-accessibility-shortcuts-for-enabling-display-color-filters

I did not find a toggle color filter shortcut anywhere. Toggling its entry in preferences plist is futile either. Nor did I find a private function to toggle it in MediaAccessibility.framework. Or any clue in console. I guess someone would need to reverse engineer the XPC to mediaaccessibilityd!
If you just need to toggle grayscale though, you can use the program in this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/410588/513458
