How can I apply a defaults value I have set in the terminal
I want to programmatically enable and disable the accessibility colour filters.
This can be achieved manually via System Settings > Accessibility > Display > Colour Filters > Colour Filters (toggle). When I do this, the change is applied immediately.
I can observe the value changing in the terminal with:
defaults read com.apple.mediaaccessibility __Color__-MADisplayFilterCategoryEnabled
# result is 0 or 1 depending on the manual change in System Settings

I can then write this value using the following command
defaults write com.apple.mediaaccessibility __Color__-MADisplayFilterCategoryEnabled <0|1>

However after running this command there is no change in the UI.
How can I have this be applied immediately in the same way that manually changing it in the System Settings is?

I'm not 100% sure, but I think you need to kill some other processes for the change to take effect to the property list (plist file) that you've edited via defaults write command. I'm not sure which process you would need to kill, but it could be something like SystemUIServer process or some other processes... You'll find that some plist changes via defaults write command won't take effect until you've logged out and back in (but note that some plists can be changed instantly with defaults write). You might have better luck creating an Apple Script instead of using defaults writes

please note that, color filters are most likely implemented in CoreGrpahics/SkyLight (WindowServer process), which may not be easy to restart without some side effects (like requiring you to relogin). You may want to use some private API like CGDisplayForceToGray(). Also check this question https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/240446/how-to-enable-disable-grayscale-mode-in-accessibility-via-terminal-app. You can also watch your console.app for subsystem com.apple.defaults read of that value by filtering for this key.
